# Performing a mathematical function as a default value MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database that stores survey results. In the database, I wish to have a cell that calculates scores from the survey being inputted into the database. 
To attempt to achieve this, I have my cell's default value set to:

```
SELECT SUM((Q1 + Q2 + Q3) * 2) FROM scores;
```

However, this returns an error in PHPMyAdmin, stating that the cell's default value is not valid.

Also, I assume that (should this work) it will calculate the sum of EVERY Q1, Q2 and Q3 field in the table. How would I go about making sure the cell only calculates the sum for the row that it exists in?

Comment: You may need to implement this as a trigger *if* you can't just do it in your application layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL `5.7` or later, you may do this via a computed column in your `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE scores (
    Q1 INT,
    Q2 INT,
    Q3 INT,
    total AS (Q1 + Q2 + Q3)
);
```